# Tagging generic browser extension/WebExtension is a mess. How to fix?

Tags: discussion, tags

[I've just asked this question about browser extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750799/why-do-browser-extensions-need-to-request-the-webrequest-body-explicitly). It is about the thing, Mozilla calls [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions).
However, due to many different namings from different vendors, if you ask a generic question that should apply to all browsers implementing the [soon to-be-standardized API](https://browserext.github.io/) you have hard times properly tagging it.

Because they have many names. MAny are more or less "historic" now or may be soon...

Browser extensions or...

- [browser-addons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser-addons) aka
- [browser-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser-extension) aka
- [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) aka
- [firefox-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-webextensions) aka
- [google-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension)

To differenciate them a little, I think the term "addon" was more common in the Mozilla world ([and actually should always be written "add-on" according to them](https://design.firefox.com/photon/copy/word-list.html#add-on)).
And as Firefox also switched to WebExtensions, I see the name `add-on` being technically deprecated and possibly only used for user-facing namings.

### Problems

1. The generic names are IMHO too generic. Maybe once we have a standard (see https://browserext.github.io/ as hinted above), we can use the real name there.
2. And we have too many tags specific to Firefox.
3. Also once we have that standard, Chrome/iums implementation/name may also change to be standard-complaint, so the tag needs to be renamed(?).
4. Finally, we just have too many tags for generic questions about the standard. (not specific to one browser)
5. As the standard/WebExtensions originated from Chrome/ium, many questions that are possible in more browsers now are still only tagged with [`google-chrome-extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension).

Generally, I think, the paradigm change is just that browser extensions also work across browsers (and will be even better in the future!).
And as we only rarely ask questions specific to a single browser for the web, we should switch to that way here, too.

At least answers can and should then list answers for all browsers, if possible. And thus a question should not ask: "How to do X in browser Y?", but "How to do X in browser extensions?".

Of the big browsers only Safari did not announce they want to take part in that standard, so of course [`safari-extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/safari-extension) cannot be replaced.

### Solutions

- Maybe **combine them**?
- Also **standardize** them, e.g. why is `google-chrome-extension` named `google-chrome-extension` and not `chrome-extension`. So shall we name `firefox-addon` also `mozilla-firefox-addon`?
  (Also why does it have an icon? I guess you have a policy for that though.)
- Maybe keep one, but only **one tag, specific to each browser**?
- About these "generic" ones: Do they even serve a purpose? (I mean, we need one for the standard, but are there really generic questions about the *concept* of add-ons/extensions in the browser?) As NPAPI plugins are deprecated and basically dead too (which may also be sorted in somewhere in "extensions"), there is no other thing anymore. So, **delete them?**

Comment: It does bother me that [google-chrome-extension] gets an icon and [firefox-webextensions] doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Web standards move *slow* and are unlikely to be commonplace for a *very* long time.  Today, a Firefox extension is not the same as a Chrome extension.

Maybe we'll get to this problem when it's actually a problem, but today?  Not really seeing the impetus.

Comment: "Today, a Firefox extension is not the same as a Chrome extension". Actually you can use the same code and do feature detection. It actually very often is the same.

Comment: "when it's actually a problem" kis today, as shown in the OP, I already asked a question concerning this problem. Otherwise I would not have opened this meta question here.

Comment: To emphasize: I constantly have to fight against the "only 5 tags max" limit when asking questions about this topic. What am I supposed to do? It is totally relevant for all these tags, but they are totally redundant/duplicates, too…

Comment: This answer is just factually wrong: Many add-ons/extensions/WebExtensions distributed use the same code base. **This is a reality!** How can you not accept reality… E.g. things like PrivacyBadger or HTTPS Everywhere or many other's…

Comment: Also, it is kind of ignorant on any web developer's mind: Usually you develop a website or so for your users, not for a _specific_ browser. The same (in broad terms) is usually possible for browser extensions too.
We also answer questions on web development with: "You can do X, but in browser Y this may fail, so do Z." …and not ask the same question for three different browsers.